# How to check is a date is 00:00:00

Tags: vb.net

I got a table that i'm quering to get the `DeliveryDate` but some of the records don't have `DeliveryDate` so VB considers that as  00:00:00.

How do I make an `IF` condition to check a date and see if it's 00:00:00?
Because I want to set a variable to **TRUE** when the date is nothing(00:00:00).

Comment: You mean if the *time* portion of the date is 0:0:0?

Comment: That's too late, this is a case of GIGO.  Garbage-in, garbage-out.  No way to tell the difference from a record that actually needed to be delivered at midnight.  If you want to ignore that then you can use DateTime.TimeOfDay()

Comment: apparently, I have found a solution, I will post it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your Date equals the date part:

`If DeliveryDate.Date = DeliveryDate Then ...`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to check if date was assigned to `Nothing`, in which case it would default to [Date.MinValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx). The quick and dirty approach would be to check:

```
If DeliveryDate = Date.MinValue Then
```

It will work fine for packages delivered at midnight, because you are unlikely to have any packages scheduled for delivery in year 1 BC.

The proper approach would be to have `DeliveryDate` of type `Nullable(Of Date)`, so you can actually store `Convert.DBNull` (=`Nothing`) in there. In this case, the code becomes easier to read:

```
If DeliveryDate Is Nothing Then
```

Note that you *could* have used a similar line at the start (with `DeliveryDate` being of type `Date`):

```
If DeliveryDate = Nothing Then
```

However, you would rather avoid implicit conversion of `Nothing` to `Date.MinValue`, which would happen behind the scenes in this case, even though it appears to be just as readable, as with `Is Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use `New Date` but it is a style choice - you can also use Nothing.

```
If DeliveryDate = New Date Then
```

or

```
If DeliveryDate = Nothing Then
```